# How can i Adding a filter ( line editing ) over each column  in ListView?

Tags: wpf

I want to add  filter over each column in ListView.
Is someone know how to do it ?

Comment: You should at least show what you did already, no one knows how your code looks like, so how should anyone help you? I think there are different ways to solve your problem, so we need to know how your code looks like to find the best way for you.

Comment: OK .. Sorry but i don't have any code now ... i just have simple listview that contain 2 tables and i want to add the ability to show information according to the filter that will be added as a string over one of the column.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could show some code (e.g. where does these listview get its data from? (the VM), the xaml, the xaml.cs)

Comment: There are tons of examples: http://bit.ly/O1ZSMw

Comment: 1.Customizing DataGridColumn template will solve the first issue                 2.To achieve filter functionality Use CollectionView.SortDescription property